# What good are Object.freeze and Object.seal if they can be overwritten?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm wondering why ECMA5's `Object.freeze` and `Object.seal` are not themselves frozen.

Are they not useless if you can just run this at the top of the page:

```
Object.freeze = function() {};
Object.seal = function() {};
```

In my tests this completely negates their use since you can't rely on their functionality.

Comment: This actually goes for most of the builtin functions -- you can render all your JavaScript useless by doing that to every method.

Comment: Could it be useful while trying to secure `eval`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Qantas94Heavy/10989540 Yeah, have fun.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Not really. You can hope to change the security level from 'wide open' to 'slightly ajar'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`freeze` and `seal` are one part of protecting your code when you will be running untrusted code, and they are useful when you control the runtime environment.  You need to freeze or seal objects before handing them to the untrusted code.

For instance, if you had a site where a user could submit code to control a robot, you would freeze the robot object, *then* pass it to the user's uploaded code.  It wouldn't matter at that point if the user tried to overwrite `freeze` or `seal`.  You wouldn't let user code execute before you had set up your environment and frozen the objects though.

Comment: yet there will be many more security holes left to exploit if you do this, won't there?

Answer (score 1):

They are useful for protecting the code from itself, not for protecting it from malicious code.

You can use them to minimise the damage that an error in your own code can do. In some ways this can be seen as a step closer to the encapsulation that is available in object oriented languages.

You can't use those methods to protect your code against various attacks. You can use them to make it somewhat harder to manipulate the code, but there are too many ways around them to offer something that you can call protection.